# LM358 opamp unity gain cap

Tags: operational-amplifier, unity-gain

I'm using an LM358 op-amp for unity gain (feedback to V-).  However, I'm getting some unexpected results.  When Vin is from 0v - 3.75v, op-amp output is as expected 0 - 3.75v.  However, when Vin is greater than 3.75v, op-amp output is capped at 3.75v, even though Vcc is 5v.  Can someone help shed some light to why op-amp unity gain can be less than 1?

[image: Op-amp sch]

LM358 datasheet can be found here:
http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/LM358-D.PDF

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's right there on page 4:

> Output Voltage−High Limit (V<sub>OH</sub>): V<sub>CC</sub> = 5.0 V, [...] | 3.3 | 3.5 | - | V

Answer (score 6):

The LM358 isn't rail-to-rail.  The output cannot be driven to Vcc.